# Javascript not working suddenly on all browsers

Tags: javascript, character, semantics

Hi I have been working on a fairly simple page with very light and common javascript (simple query, less, a slider I've used before) Everything was just great until randomly all javascript stopped working in all browswers. My web inspector says this
[image]

All my javascript is showing up in another language in the web inspector and says "Semantic issue invalid character /u12709" I don't even know where that character is. When this happened  I wasn't even working on javascript. I copied some text into the html, just copy. You can see the full page at densciencega.com or here is just the head code

```
<head>
<title>Dent Science</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/yfc0oou.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="main.less" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/smooth.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but that unicode characters that I've checked are "undefined". http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/unicode.php?char=10799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your local copy of the JavaScript file correct, and only appears broken once you upload it?

Try changing your FTP settings to force binary upload instead of ASCII - I've seen this happen before with FileZilla using ASCII uploads.

Comment: All of this is already uploaded. I built the whole thing online using coda. It does not work offline either

Comment: OK - the page loads fine in Internet Explorer, but fails in FireFox and Chrome (where the scripts show Asian characters). In Internet Explorer, it says that the page is being interpreted as UTF-16 instead of UTF-8, and FireFox says UTF-16 as well. Maybe this is causing the browsers to interpret all the JS files as UTF-16? IE also mentions an invalid character at line 198, character 57 (which I can see if I view the source in Notepad++) - maybe this is causing the browsers to misinterpret the file encoding?

Comment: It must be the invalid character.

Comment: THANKS djhayman. You were right somehow it was set to UTF-16. I have no clue how that happened. I converted back and now it works great!